# hive: select and count repeated trips

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

14 in Hortonworks data platform (HDP) for a school project, and i have to analyze the entries of a NY taxi. I want to find out the repeated trips (same pickup and drop off location) with the data that follows as an example:

| tripid | pulocationid | dolocationid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | 31 |
| 1 | 12 | 42 |
| 2 | 5 | 34 |
| 3 | 12 | 31 |
| 4 | 7 | 76 |
| 5 | 5 | 34 |
| 6 | 5 | 34 |

resulting in:

| pulocationid | dolocationid | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 31 | 2 |
| 5 | 34 | 3 |

I was thinking in using an inner self join, but I believe that I am taking a bad approach since the MAPREDUCE job never starts and shows an error (not any reason whatsoever):

```
select pulocationid,    dolocationid, count(tripid) from yellowtaxi22 picks inner join yellowtaxi22 drops
on( picks.pulocationid=drops.pulocationid and picks.dolocationid=drops.dolocationid)
group by pulocationid;
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal group by on both columns on Hive(appropriate version) should do if I catch the question right.

```
select pulocationid, dolocationid, count(*) from trips group by pulocationid, dolocationid;
```

This gives me an output like:

```
        5   34  2
        12  31  2
        7   76  1
        12  42  1
        34  10  1
```